# Why Global API response is showing nil in swift

Tags: json, swift, global

I made `getUser` service call globally but when i call that method in required viewcontroller then data coming nil.. why?

**code:** created `user_details` API service call globally.. here `UserDetailsModel` is JSON response model for user_details API.
**when i give breakpoint then `GET_USER` is called and response also coming globally**

```
 import UIKit

// to get user

var GET_USER = UserDetailsModel(dictionary: NSDictionary())

func getUser(vc: UIViewController) {

APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: nil, method: .post, vc: vc, url: CommonUrl.user_details, isTokenNeeded: true){ [] (resp) in
            
    GET_USER = UserDetailsModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
}
}
```

when i am calling `getUser` in EditProfileVC then breakpoint not going inside `GET_USER{ didSet{` why?

how to show global `user_details` API response in `EditProfileVC`. please guide me.

```
 import UIKit

 class EditProfileVC: UIViewController {

private var getUserData = GET_USER{
    didSet{// breakpoint not hitting inside why?
        
        locationTf.text = getUserData?.result?.userData?.lives_in
        dobTf.text = getUserData?.result?.userData?.dob
        educationTf.text = getUserData?.result?.userData?.education
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    getUser(vc: self)
}
}
```

Comment: *I made getUser service call globally* Don't. In your case put it into an `extension` of `UIViewController`. And don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift at all. And conform to the naming convention. UPPER_SNAKE_CASE is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

private var getUserData = GET_USER{
change to
public var getUserData = GET_USER{


GET_USER = UserDetailsModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
change to
vc.getUserData = UserDetailsModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not setting **getUserData** in the view controller.

you should return a value from your **getUser()** function like

```
func getUser() -> UserDetailsModel
```

and in your **viewDidLoad**

```
getUserData = getUser(vc: self)
```